# How to open a file in python, read the comments ("#"), find a word after the comments and select the word after it?

Tags: python, if-statement, string-matching

I have a function that loops through a file that Looks like this:

```
"#" XDI/1.0 XDAC/1.4 Athena/0.9.25

"#" Column.4:                      pre_edge

Content
```

That is to say that after the "#" there is a comment. My function aims to read each line and if it starts with a specific word, select what is after the ":"

For example if I had These two lines. I would like to read through them and if the line starts with "#" and contains the word "Column.4" the word "pre_edge" should be stored.

An example of my current approach follows:

```
with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith ('#'):
                word = line.split(" Column.4:")[1]
            else:
                print("n")
```

I think my Trouble is specifically after finding a line that starts with "#" how can I parse/search through it? and save its Content if it contains the desidered word.

Comment: Sounds like a problem for [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) (short for regular expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case that `#` comment contain str `Column.4:` as stated above, you could parse it this way.

```py
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            # Here you proceed comment lines
            if 'Column.4' in line:
                first, remainder = line.split('Column.4: ')
                # Remainder contains everything after '# Column.4: '
                # So if you want to get first word ->
                word = remainder.split()[0]
        else:
            # Here you can proceed lines that are not comments
            pass
```

#### Note

Also it is a good practice to use `for line in f:` statement instead of `f.readlines()` (as mentioned in other answers), because this way you don't load all lines into memory, but proceed them one by one.

Comment: This worked great for the comments. But after the comment lines, I have some Content is still been read line by line. I added:
    else:
         data = line.strip().split()
but only adds the last line of the file, and does not appends the lines without comments. How could I do that?

Comment: @Luis Carlos Colocho Hurtarte I've updated my answer. If i understand correctly that except comment lines you want to proceed regular lines, then adding `else` statement should work. Just be careful to put `else` clause on correct level. In python there exist `for-else` statement, so if you put `else` on the same level as `for` it would capture only the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading the file into a list and then work through that instead:

```
file = 'test.txt' #<- call file whatever you want
with open(file, "r") as f:
    txt = f.readlines()
    for line in txt:
        if line.startswith ('"#"'):
            word = line.split(" Column.4: ")
            try:
                print(word[1])
            except IndexError:
                print(word)
        else:
            print("n")
```

Output:

```
>>> ['"#" XDI/1.0 XDAC/1.4 Athena/0.9.25\n']
>>> pre_edge
```

Used a try and except catch because the first line also starts with *"#"* and we can't split that with your current logic.

Also, as a side note, in the question you have the file with lines starting as *"#"* with the quotation marks so the `startswith()` function was altered as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('stuff.txt', 'r+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    words = line.split()
    if words and ('#' in words[0]) and ("Column.4:" in words):
        print(words[-1])

# pre_edge
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation.Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find how to write a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful.